# how does work the creation of indexes when the index is part of a closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

In the following code I'm confused about the line with the comment "here!":

```
var foo = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    (function(){
     var y = i;
     foo[i] = function(){return y;} //here!
 })();
}
```

**Why the "i" value creates the indexes of "foo" correctly?** At the end when we try to consult its value is 10. So, why don'tnwe have something like:

content of foo: foo[10] //10 (having only this position in this array)

I understand that we have a closure over "i", because we are making a reference related to another scope, **but what I don't understand is why the indexes for "foo" were created correctly having a closure over the "i" variable.**

Comment: Your IIFE is executed immediately once per iteration, and uses the current value of `i`. It's only the inner functions created inside the IIFE that need a closure to work properly, because those functions would be called later (although the code shown never calls them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's useful to look at a single iteration of the loop to understand what is happening.

Let's say `i = 3`:

You create an anonymous function and assign `y = i` which makes `y` point to the value `3`, ie. the value of `y` doesn't depend on `i` afterwards. Then you set `foo[3] = function() {return y; // return 3`. The key point is that `i` changing won't change the values of `y`.

The only relevant closure here is the one which grants `foo[i]` access to `y` despite the outer anonymous function having been fully executed and finished.

Also note that each iteration declares a new `var y` which points to the value in `i` for **that iteration only**. So each function returns a separate `y` in a separate execution context.

---

Compare to the following code, which does not have an intermediate variable (like the `y` in your code) and so `i` refers to the **actual value** of `i` in the enclosing scope -- that is, 10, the value of `i` after the loop has finished

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    (function(){
     foo[i] = function(){return i;} 
 })();
}

foo[3] = 10; // as you expected for your code
```

Another example below which is similar to yours and has the same behaviour, the parameter to the outer anonymous function holds the value which the inner function is closed over.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    (function(x){
     foo[i] = function(){return x;}
 })(i); // notice that we pass i in here
}

foo[3] = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it works is that your inner function is called synchronously from within the loop.

Common problems occur -- with referencing an outer *index* in a nested function -- when that function is called *asynchronously*, or at least *after* the loop has been executed completely, which is not your case.

Example where it *would* go wrong:

```
var foo = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var y = i;
        foo[i] = function(){return y;} //here!
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why the `i` value creates the indices of `foo` correctly:**

In javascript a list is just an object underneath. Using the `[]` accessor on a variable creates a map from the contents of `[]` to an assigned value. You are mapping the key `i` to a function that returns the value of `y`.

**Why the indexes for `foo` were created correctly having a closure over the `i` variable:**

You are storing references to functions in the loop. If you were to do the following I believe you will get the result you expected:

```
foo[10]() // This will return 10.
```

**References:**

[Insert into array at non-existent index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850637/insert-into-array-at-non-existent-index)